# How to pass function with parameters in a dictionary key value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and was trying to create a dictionary with value as a function. here is my code

```
import os

class Foo():
    def print1(self,n):
        print 5


    def print2(self,n):
        print 6

    def foo(self):
        bar = {'a': self.print1, 'b': self.print2}
        bar['b'](5)
        bar['a'](3)
        bar[os.environ['FOO']]()


f = Foo()
f.foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dict.py", line 17, in <module>
   f.foo()
  File "test_dict.py", line 13, in foo
    bar[b]()

python test_dict.py 
6 
5  
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_dict.py", line 19, in <module>
       f.foo()
      File "test_dict.py", line 15, in foo
       bar[os.environ['FOO']]()
    TypeError: print2() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Your functions aren't returning anything. Thus, `bar[b]` is `None`. And so, the error, `NoneType not callable`

Comment: There is no reason you can't put a callable as a dictionary value. However, in this case, you're putting *the output of the functions* in the dictionary.

Comment: What does ```os.environ['FOO']``` evaluate to?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't make sense. The exception says ` bar[b]()` but your code says `bar['b'](5)`

Comment: Try ```bar[os.environ['FOO']]('baz')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class Foo():
    def print1(self,n):
        print 6

    def print2(self,n):
        print n

    def foo(self):
        bar = {'a': self.print1, 'b': self.print2 }
        bar['b'](5)
        bar['a'](3)

f = Foo()
f.foo()
```

It does what you want.

Comment: the above comment is still giving me the error. Here is the code:                'import os

class Foo():
    def print1(self):
        print 5


    def print2(self):
        print 6

    def foo(self):
        bar = {'a': self.print1, 'b': self.print2 }
        bar['b'](5)
        bar['a'](3)
        bar[os.environ['FOO']]()


f = Foo()
f.foo()'

Comment: and here is the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dict.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.foo()
  File "test_dict.py", line 13, in foo
    bar['b'](5)
TypeError: print2() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @user3034987 That exact code works for me. You should update your question to include the exact code you are trying to run.

Comment: @user3034987 Your `print1` and `print2` definitions in the above comment take only `self` as parameter whereas its supposed to be `self, n`. Change that and your error will go away.

Comment: added the exact code i am running along with the output. Still i am getting the error after adding argument variable

Answer (score 1):

`bar = {'a': self.print1(6), 'b': self.print2(5) }` doesn't store the functions as the values in the dictionary.

It calls the functions `print1` and `print2` and stores their return values. Since both the functions only `print` and don't return anything, you get the dictionary `{'a': None, 'b': None }` which is why you are getting the `NoneType` exception.

Instead, you should do:

`bar = {'a': self.print1, 'b': self.print2 }`

Then:

```
bar['b'](5)
>> 5
```

Comment: Tried that as well, but it didn't worked. See my comments in the above post.

Comment: @user3034987 That exact code works for me. You should update your question to include the exact code you are trying to run.

Comment: updated the code with the exact code i am running and the output i am getting.  i am setting FOO as b in this case

Comment: @user3034987 `bar[os.environ['FOO']]()` both your functions expect 2 arguments, but you are attempting to call one of them with no arguments.

Answer (score -1):

The way you do it, the function gets called and the result gets stored (which is None because you don't return anything), if you want the function to be callable as such, you could either write a `lambda` around it or use `functools.partial`

Comment: What is wrong with simply passing the name without parenthesis in?

Comment: Nothing, it didn't occur to me that that could be what he wanted. The code looks to me as if he wanted to fix a parameter, which is the purpose of partial. Then it could be called as bar[b]() instead of bar[b](5).

Comment: You are right... It sounds like he wanted to pass the function with an argument. That wouldn't be possible with the reference only. But the sense behind all this is very questionable... ^^